# Running thousands of NodeJS apps

Tags: node.js, scaling, middleware

I would like to start writing lots of tiny "utility" NodeJS-based apps -- things like stream filters, generators, and the like, that might be 30-40LOC each. Each one would consume nearly zero CPU, RAM, or bandwidth (when the overhead of NodeJS and OS processes are factored out).  The point is, I want a simple way to run thousands of them.

What do I need? Are there any PaaS's that can run thousands of NodeJS apps for a reasonable price ($10/mo)? Is there some kind of middleware that can give me thousands of sandboxed "partitions" on top of one Node process? Or is there some binary that's made for this that I could put on a VPS?

Comment: Do you have a programming question? As written, this isn't currently a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vm](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module for sandboxing javascript code. It is still in works, be sure to read the [caveats](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_caveats).
Functions that you can use:

1. runInThisContext: runs code in a separate context (but has access to global vars, not local).
2. runInNewContext: takes a seperate set of global var for context.
3. runInContext: takes a Context object(previously defined), for running the code.